# Magento configurable products doesn't show attribute set inside tabs

Tags: magento, configurable-product

I add some associated products to a configurable product. I used many attributes defined in attribute set "Phone_specification" for example for configurable phone.
It is supposed to show these specifications as a table (like CPU, GPU, LCD quality, ... so that to be compared later or ...) inside tabs below main description of configurable product.
But it shows nothing. It ignores these attributes which have been defined for configurable product. But in individual associated items it shows properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tab on the product detail page that shows a list of product attributes will only show the attributes and their values assigned for that product.  If it's a configurable product, it will not show the attributes for the simple products, because there could be more than one value.

If you want information to appear there, assign the attributes and values to the configurable product and they should appear.

Also for the attributes to appear on the Product View Page, you must make sure that the `Visible on Product View Page on Front-end` is set to `Yes` for that product.

1. Go to **Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes**
2. Click the attribute you want to appear on the product view page.
3. Set the option **Visible on Product View Page on Front-end** to `Yes`
4. Hit the **Save** button and flush your Magento caches.

Your attributes will now on the product view pages **for the products they are directly assigned to**.

Comment: I have assigned attributes to configurable product too. But still no list. During creation of configurable product, I assign attribute set to it. Then I define all attributes for configurable product. No list in details appears!

Comment: I've updated my answer with a second step.  You need to make sure they are set to be visible on the frontend pages.

Comment: I don't want it *for the products they are directly assigned* to be shown. Instead I want it just for *configurable product* to be shown. Because I want my associated products (that is black, white, yellow,... phones individually) to be hidden. Instead just a configurable phone to be shown with attributes (CPU,RAM,GPU,LCD,...). You can say what pain in the back it would be if user is directed to each individual phone to see specifications (attributes)!

Comment: What you're asking for is exactly what I've outlined in my answer.  I'm not referring to configurable product associations when I said "for the products they are directly assigned to".  What I'm saying is the product view page will only show the attributes that are directly assigned to the item being viewed.  If it's a configurable product, then attributes assigned directly to that configurable product will appear (as long as they are set to frontend visibility: yes).

Comment: Thank you VERY VERY much. Brilliant answer means it cost me a lot of time yet simple trick turns out to be the key :)